# Разные хеши(хеширование через сайт и на языке С#)

Tags: c#, хеширование, sha

Ниже код для хеширование строки("1:3") в Keccak512:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using HashLib; // https://www.nuget.org/packages/HashLib/

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Keccak512("1:3"));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        public static string Keccak512(string str)
        {
            var hash = HashFactory.Crypto.SHA3.CreateKeccak512();
            var result = hash.ComputeBytes(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str.ToUpper()));
            return result.ToString().Replace("-", "");
        }
    }
}
```

Результат:

```
EEC9F6F1C74323D2858FBE72499F9EF66550D38328394C5609DB959A98E7261AE66D59F199575CB25D7AF6427807FEBBFBCDC03554B615871F9397517E590D7A
```

**Хеширование через сайт строки("1:3"):** *https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/sha3_512.html*

```
c6f9ff1181daa7104920995cabab6f196bdc4d96666987172f5a5788aae447c23097698cb56b1eb2d389c764b30d0ed789d75e4665bab7726b858b2fbbf26499
```

Comment: Очень сложный вопрос. У алгоритмов шифрования - есть опции. Попробуйте другие опции. Если другие опции не помагают - то возможно у кого-то из вас двоих ошибка в алгоритме. Попробуйте скачать другие библиотеки шифрования. Может конкретно данная попалась битая. Попробуйте проверить на других сайтах, возможно ошибка на сайте.

Comment: @nick_n_a Меня беспокоит то, что на всех сайтах, выдает такой хеш, а именно у меня другой. Я пробовал все опции, пробовал строку хешировать, пробовал байты(как в примере выше)

Comment: Тогда скачайте другую либу. На крайний случай - скачайте плюсовую (с++) проверьте и затем  портируйте на с# (я для некоторых алгоритмов так делал, потому что не смог найти такую которая даёт тот же хеш что и плюсовые, но работа нудная)

Comment: Можно написать автору библиотеки... но не уверен что они быстро баг исправят.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вроде-как библиотека [BouncyCastle](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BouncyCastle/) смогла.

```csharp
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Digests;
```

```csharp
public static string Keccak512(string str)
{
    KeccakDigest keccak = new KeccakDigest(512);

    byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str);
    byte[] result = new byte[keccak.GetDigestSize()];

    keccak.BlockUpdate(data, 0, data.Length);
    keccak.DoFinal(result, 0);

    return BitConverter.ToString(result).Replace("-", "").ToLowerInvariant();
}
```

Вывод в консоль для `Console.WriteLine(Keccak512("1:3"))`

```
c6f9ff1181daa7104920995cabab6f196bdc4d96666987172f5a5788aae447c23097698cb56b1eb2d389c764b30d0ed789d75e4665bab7726b858b2fbbf26499
```

Сверил хэш с https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/keccak_512.html, совпадает.

Comment: Оказывается я перепутал при хешировании на сайте "SHA 3-512" и "Keccak-512". Ваш код хеширует в "SHA 3-512", а мне нужно "Keccak-512". Сижу уже часов 6 над этим...утомительно

Comment: @Netahaki обновил ответ.

Comment: Все благодарности.

Comment: @Netahaki я не контактный (сложная, но актуальная шутка). Пишите свои вопросы (но не все подряд) на StackOverflow, я здесь часто бываю.

Comment: Я хочу за помощь отблагодарить